# How to get the page records from radgrid when click on button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radgrid

I am using Telerik RadGrid.i bind the data (i.e 10 rows) to radgrid with paging .the paging was set to 5 per page.the radgrid as Hirarchial mode.

i am get the first page records only when user click on button.which i need to send a mail.how can retrive all the data

Comment: please check http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/retrieving-all-the-records-in-radgrid-saving.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
RadGridAllocateEmployee.AllowPaging = False
RadGridAllocateEmployee.Rebind()
        'Your code
For Each item As GridDataItem In RadGridAllocateEmployee.MasterTableView.Items
. . . . . . .
Next
RadGridAllocateEmployee.AllowPaging = True
RadGridAllocateEmployee.Rebind()
```